# Positioning a Button over more than a single cell in Gridview

Tags: c#, windows, gridview, gantt-chart

I am drawing a schedule Gantt where a task can start from 10.25 AM until 11.15 AM whereas my grid is in an hourly format. I am using a c# gridview by setting a Datatable as a source which has each cell representing single hour. I am not looking to draw tasks allocated on the Gantt where a task can start in between hours.

Please help to draw a button in grid control view where it can span across cells partially. Please see image for details.

[image]

Comment: You might want to write your own control for something like this. Since it's time based, I would use two attached properties for the layouting and use the control like a Panel. A gridview is **not** the suitable tool for this.

Comment: Are you really using a GridView or actually a DataGridView?? They are different controls!! Always use the right name! - Aslo how is the red blob a Button? And why? So you actually don't want to draw?

Comment: You also need to specify a) what data are in  the control and how can it be interacted with. As it stands the question is both unclear and too broad! - Maybe you actually want [this chart type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580398/segmented-bar-chart-in-winforms-devexpress/49581523#49581523) ??